# How can you determine the original data length when decrypting message with padding?

Tags: c#, encryption, aes, protocol-buffers

I have an AES-128 encrypted byte array, using PaddingMode.Zeros. I am decrypting it just fine, but when the data ends in zeros I can't figure out where the data ends and padding begins. We are using AesCryptoServiceProvider and ICryptoTransform for encrypt and decrypt.

This is an issue because I'm trying to parse the unencrypted byte array as a protocol buffer. If I try to parse the entire array with the extra data, I get an error "Google.Protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: Protocol message contained an invalid tag (zero)". If I remove too many of the zeros (all of them) I get another error "Google.Protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: While parsing a protocol message, the input ended unexpectedly in the middle of a field". I've tried using Google.Protobufers, and Protobuf.net they both give similar errors.

How do I tell how much padding was in that array? Or, is there a way to prevent the error when parsing the data into a protobuf?

Comment: What you have found is why padding with zeros is often a bad idea.  It should only be used with fixed length data, so the data size is known in advance.  Use PKCS7 instead, which is always removable.  Alternatively try all possible lengths of zero padding, one should work.

Comment: Yeah, that's a good suggestion. Unfortunately I'm dealing with existing code that can't really be changed easily.

Comment: Then you'll have to chop off the trailing zeros one at a time, trying to decrypt the remainder after every chop.  Tedious but doable.

Comment: Does the decrypted data contains some length field(s) that would allow you to calculate the size of the protobuf data and hence where the padding starts?

Comment: I hacked in a length on a repurposed part of the file, it's not super clean, but it is what it is. I couldn't make major changes to the file because it has to be shared between platforms, and could not require the others to change. I think the C library being used in firmware did not throw an exception if there was extra data in the buffer.

Answer (score 0):

Using `PaddingMode.Zeros` is not recommended in most cases. It is normally only used when you are encrypting data, which is guaranteed to contain only non-zero bytes (otherwise padding can't be removed automatically). Use PKCS7, which is most common type of padding and can be freely used with any type of data.

Comment: I agree that's the best solution, I'm just trying to fix a bug in existing code and don't have the ability to change the file format easily. I kinda figured there wasn't a good way fix it without changing file to add a length, or change the padding.